# Will Buffer with glMapBuffer be allocated a slower VRAM than glBufferSubData?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I have a large data to transfer to the buffer such as VBO or IndirectDrawBuffer, and I used glMapBuffer and glBufferSubData to do this. I found buffer uploaded by using glMapBuffer is much slower than using glBufferSubData when the buffer was rendered.
I allocate the buffer like this

```
glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, m_indirectDrawBuffer);
glBufferStorage(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, buffersize, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
```

And I used glMapBuffer like this

```
m_indirectDrawBufferPtr = (GLubyte*)glMapNamedBuffer(m_indirectDrawBuffer, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
memcpy(m_indirectDrawBufferPtr, m_MultidrawCommands.data(), buffersize);
glUnmapNamedBuffer(m_indirectDrawBuffer);
```

And I used glBufferSubData like this

```
glNamedBufferSubData(m_indirectDrawBuffer, 0, buffersize, m_MultidrawCommands.data());
```

Why did these happen?

What should I do to get an efficient buffer by using glMapBuffer? Allocate 2 buffers, one using glMapBuffer and the other using glCopyNamedBufferSubData to copy data from the first buffer, maybe a way to solve these. But it will use more VRAM. Is it the only way?

Comment: Why are you using direct state access for some of your functions, but not *all* of them (like `glBufferStorage`)?

Answer (score 1):

First, you're not allowed to map that buffer, so it's not clear why your code is working. When you [allocate immutable storage for a buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Immutable_Storage), you have to specify how you intend to access it. And you didn't say that you would map it for reading or writing... so you *can't*.

Second, mapping a buffer is a fairly heavyweight operation. If you already have data in a block of memory, there's no point in mapping a buffer just to copy it and then immediately unmap it. Mapping allows you to generate that data *directly* into the buffer (in theory), so whatever operation you used to fill in `m_MultidrawCommands` should have been used to write directly to the mapped buffer.

Also, [persistent mapping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Persistent_mapping) exists, which allows you to keep a buffer mapped in perpetuity. Of course, that also requires you to keep track of what commands are *using* part of the buffer, so that you don't write to values that may be read from.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But first, if what you are talking is like GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT, I have tried and got the same result. Second, I didn't copy the memory just like this, it's a simple example. Actually, I copy the memory data in a thread, because it's a large data and I don't want to jam the CPU to transfer by using glBufferSubData

Comment: Also tried glBufferData(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, buffersize, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW) to allocate buffer got the same result either